# Set each elements's Html from its attribute

Tags: jquery, loops

Instead of writing a loop like this:

```
$s.find("td.value").each(function() {
     $(this).html($(this).attr("data-value"));
});
```

Is there a way to do this in one shot ?
Something like:

```
$s.find("td.value").html($(this).attr("data-value"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [function argument of the html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html-functionindex--oldhtml) to return the new html. But it doesn't make much difference since jquery internally loops through the items.

```
$s.find("td.value").html(function(){ //Has 2 arguments second one will be the current html representation of the element and first argument the index of the item in the collection
   return $(this).data("value");
});
```